# Windows 10 custom file icon

Tags: windows-10, icons, filetype

On previous editions of Windows there was a "File type" configuration page, where users could choose the default application for a given file type and also choose a custom icon, if the default one is missing or ugly.
Unfortunately, this feature has been removed in Windows 10. 
So, how can I set a custom icon for a file type in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article on Windows Dev Center, but it's not working on Windows 10 or in my particular situation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type

I had to change the icon associated to .pdf files, since the default icon shipped with Acrobat isn't so cute.

This is the original configuration on the Windows registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AcroExch.Document.DC\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\Installer\\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1040-7B44-AC0F074E4100}\\PDFFile_8.ico,0"
```

Simply change file icon path and it does the trick:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AcroExch.Document.DC\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe,0"
```